# "chain" the addition operator into a function that accepts 3 arguments?

Tags: function, haskell, composition

I'd like to compose the addition operator `(+)` to make a function of this type:

```
Num a => a -> a -> a -> a
```

Like, the equivalent of this:

```
(\a b c -> a + b + c)
```

but without having to resort to lambdas.

---

I tried already

```
((+) . (+))
```

which I would have expected to work but surprisingly didn't.

Comment: Iirc, composure requires the function to only accept 1 argument. The binary operators each take 2

Comment: And why not just fold over the list using `+`?

Comment: @Carcigenicate hmm, that's strange. I wouldn't have expected that to be the case. Is there any way to do it though? - edit: and what's fold, and what list?

Comment: @minseong: a list is a type `[a]`. `foldl` runs a function over the elements of a list so if you give `(+)` as function, `foldl (+) 0 ls` will return `0+ls!!0+ls!!1+...+ls!!n` (but more efficient than using `(!!)`).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I know what a list is, I just don't get where Carcigenicate is seeing a list within my code

Comment: @minseong It looks like you're just trying to add a series of numbers, so putting them in a list and summing them seemed like an easy solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://pointfree.io gives the point-free version of `\a b c -> a + b + c` as `((+) .) . (+)`.

Informally, composition only works "intuitively" for first-order functions, which neither take functions as arguments nor return functions as values. `(+)` is a higher-order function; it takes a value of type `Num a => a`, and returns a function of type `Num a => a -> a`. When you try to compose higher-order functions in a naive fashion, the result is not what you expect:

```
:t (+) . (+)
(+) . (+) :: (Num a, Num (a -> a)) => a -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
```

Consider the definitions of the two functions:

```
(+) :: Num z => z -> z -> z
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
f . g = \x -> f (g x)
```

Then

```
(+) . (+) == (.) (+) (+)
          == \x -> (+) ((+) x)
```

Because of currying, you wind up passing a function, not a number, as the first argument of the first `(+)`.

---

So how do we get from `h a b c = a + b + c` to `h = ((+) .) . (+)`? Start by rewriting the infix expression as a prefix expression, using the fact that `(+)` is left-associative.

```
\a b c -> a + b + c
     == \a b c -> ((+) a b ) + c
     == \a b c -> (+) ((+) a b) c
```

Next, we alternately apply eta conversion to eliminate an argument and composition to move an argument into position to be eliminated. I've tried to be very explicit about identifying the functions use for the application of composition.

```
     == \a b -> (+) ((+) a b)      -- eta conversion to eliminate c
     == \a b -> (+) (((+) a) b)    -- parentheses justified by currying
     --          f      g          -- f = (+), g = ((+) a)
     -- \a b ->  f  (   g    b)
     -- \a b -> (f   .  g)   b     -- definition of (.)
     == \a b -> ((+) . ((+) a)) b
     == \a -> (+) . ((+) a)        -- eta conversion to eliminate b
     == \a -> (.) (+) ((+) a)      -- prefix notation
     == \a -> ((.) (+)) ((+) a)    -- parentheses justified by currying
     == \a -> ((+) . )((+) a)      -- back to a section of (.)
     --           f       g        -- f = ((+) .), g = (+)
     -- \a ->     f     (g a)
     -- \a -> (   f   .   g) a     -- definition of (.)
     == \a -> (((+) .) . (+)) a
     == ((+) .) . (+)              -- eta conversion to eliminate a
```

Comment: It would be illustrative to analyze the working of `((+) .) . (+)`.

Answer (score 8):

You need this strange operator `(.).(.)`, which is sometimes defines as `.:` (think of 3 dots ...)

In ghci

```
Prelude> let (.:) = (.).(.)
Prelude> let f = (+) .: (+) 
Prelude> f 1 2 3 
> 6
```

Note this operator can also be defined as `<$$> = fmap . fmap`.

Answer (score 6):

Although this introduces some noise, you could use `uncurry :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a,b) -> c` and `curry :: ((a,b) -> c) -> a -> b -> c` to temporary store the arguments of the second plus in one tuple:

```
curry $ (+) . uncurry (+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a -> a
```

or perhaps more semantically readable:

```
curry ((+) . uncurry (+)) :: Num a => a -> a -> a -> a
```

`uncurry` thus takes a function (here `(+)`) and transforms it into a function: `uncurry (+) :: Num a => (a,a) -> a`. So as a result you have transformed the `(+)` into a **function that takes a tuple**.

Now we can use `(.)` to make a composition with the first `(+)`:

```
(+) . uncurry (+) :: Num a => (a,a) -> (a -> a)
```

So now we have a function that takes one argument (the tuple `(a,a)`) and produces a function that takes an `a` (the second operand of the first `(+)`) and calculates the sum. The problem is of course that we want to get rid of the tuple. We can do so by passing the function into a `curry`. That transforms the tuple-function (`(a,a) -> (a -> a)`) into a function taking the arguments separately (`a -> (a -> (a -> a))`).

Answer (score 4):

Note the signature of the function composition operator:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
          ^            ^          ^
               Functions
```

It takes 2 functions, each which take 1 argument, and returns a function that takes an argument of the same type as the second function, and returns the same type as the first.

Your attempt to compose two `+`s didn't work since `+` takes 2 arguments, so without some hackish/creative workaround, this isn't possible.

At this point, I'd say forcing composition when it doesn't fit the problem is just going to make your life more difficult.

If you want to sum up multiple numbers, you could write a function like:

```
sum :: [Int] -> Int
sum nums = foldl (+) 0 nums
```

Or, since `nums` appears at the back of the definition, it can be dropped altogether, yielding a "point-free" form:

```
sum :: [Int] -> Int
sum = foldl (+) 0
```

It reduces/folds `+` over a list of numbers. If you haven't used folds yet, ***look into them now***. They are one of the main ways to achieve looping in Haskell. It's essentially "implicit recursion" when you're dealing with lists, or anything else iterable.

With the above function defined, you can use it like:

```
sum [1, 2  3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: I think you should write `foldr (+) 0 nums` (with brackets) and `=` instead of `::` in the assignment. It is usually also more memory efficient to use `foldl` over `foldr` given the function is commutative.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Whoops. Idk how I ended up using colons in place of a equals. And thanks, I'll change the fold.

Comment: you still need to put brackets over `(+)` otherwise Haskell sees this as `(+) foldl 0`...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks. Evidently it's been too long since I've written Haskell. I only answered because at the time I started writing, no one else had shown an interest in the question.